# Como agregar ruta al path

Tags: macos, rutas, terminal, zsh

Una pregunta rapida , necesito agregar esta ruta al PATH ya que con MacOSCatalina se paso de **bash** a **zsh** con lo cual hay rutas que no me reconoce, una de ellas es mi ruta:

```
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin'
```

Necesito añadir esa ruta a mi PATH(me lo dice la propia terminal al instalar virtualenv, ya que lo desinstale y lo volvi  a instalar) este es mi PATH:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar la ruta dentro de la declaracion de `PATH` si tienes permisos de escritura (asumo que si)

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:$PATH"
```

Utilizando `:` entre cada directorio declarado puedes unir distintos directorios a tu `$PATH`.
Recuerda siempre agregar `$PATH` a la declaración, da igual si lo ponen al principio o al final.

Comment: te refieres a ¿sudo?, por cierto ya intente hacer eso y no funciono, lo hice sin utilizar sudo si es a lo que te refieres

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias!!